# Class not found exception for applet

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet

I just finished making an applet in netbeans. But when I try to reach it using the jar file it gives me a Class not found exception error. Below are the details of the error:

Java Plug-in 10.45.2.18
Using JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

### User home directory = C:\Users\C.C

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

### 0-5: set trace level to

0

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-4" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.exit(Unknown Source)
    at TicTacToe$ButtonListener.runAI(TicTacToe.java:155)
    at TicTacToe$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(TicTacToe.java:105)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code for the html.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minigames for All</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 id="header">Welcome to Minigames for All.</h2>
        <hr>

        <div id="script">
        <object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
            <param name="code" value="slime2" />
            <param name="archive" value="applet/slime2.jar" />
            Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
        </object>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="rps.html">Rock, Paper, Scissors</td>
                    <td><a href="random.html">Guess the Number</td>
                    <td><a href="ttt.html">Tic Tac Toe</td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><a href="flip.html">Flip a Coin</td>
                    <td><a href="rpg.html">Slime RPG</td>
                    <td><a href="shoot.html">Space Shooter</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                    <td><a href="index.html">Home Page</td>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for the applet:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import java.util.Random;
/**
 *
 * @author C.C
 */
public class slime extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    Random rng = new Random();
    int choice;
    int player = 100;
    int king = 100;
    int slime = 50;
    /**
     * Initializes the applet slime
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        choice = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
        if(choice >=7)
        {
            battle.append("You are the hero. You have 100 health." + "\n");
            battle.append("You encountered a King Slime!" + "\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            battle.append("You are the hero. You have 100 health." + "\n");
            battle.append("You encountered a slime!" + "\n\n");
        }
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(slime.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        battle = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        attack = new javax.swing.JButton();
        heal = new javax.swing.JButton();
        charge = new javax.swing.JButton();
        run = new javax.swing.JButton();

        battle.setColumns(20);
        battle.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(battle);

        attack.setText("Attack");
        attack.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                attackActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        heal.setText("Heal");
        heal.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                healActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        charge.setText("Charge");
        charge.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                chargeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        run.setText("Run");
        run.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                runActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(heal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(attack, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(charge, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(run, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(attack)
                    .addComponent(charge))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 19, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(heal)
                    .addComponent(run))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void attackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int damage = rng.nextInt(10)+1;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
            if(damage >=7)
            {
                battle.append("You did "+ String.valueOf(damage)+ " damage. It was a critcal hit!" + "\n");
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                battle.append("You did "+ String.valueOf(damage)+ " damage." + "\n");
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The Slime King hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
            }
       }
    }                                      

    private void healActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        int heal = rng.nextInt(40)+20;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
           battle.append("You healed for " + heal + " health.\n");
           player = player+heal;
           if (choice >=7)
                {               
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");       
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
       }
    }                                    

    private void chargeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        int damage = rng.nextInt(30)+10;
       int damage2 = rng.nextInt(25)+10;
       int damage3 = rng.nextInt(20)+5;
       if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       else
       {
            battle.append("You skip a turn to charge a more powerful attack!" +"\n");
            if (choice >=7)
                {               
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");       
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            if(player <=0)
            {
                battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (choice >=7)
                {
                    battle.append("You unleash a powerful attack at the King Slime for " + damage + " damage.\n");
                    king = king-damage;
                    battle.append("The King Slime has " + king + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(king <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the King Slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The King Slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage2) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage2;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    battle.append("You unleash a powerful attack at the slime for " + damage + " damage.\n");
                    slime = slime-damage;
                    battle.append("The slime has " + slime + " health left!" + "\n");
                    if(slime <=0)
                    {
                        battle.append("You have defeated the slime!" + "\n\n");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    battle.append("The slime hit you for " + String.valueOf(damage3) + " damage!" + "\n");
                    player = player-damage3;
                    if(player < 0)
                    {
                        player = 0;
                    }
                    battle.append("You have "+ String.valueOf(player) + " health left." + "\n\n");                  
                }
            }

       }
    }                                      

    private void runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        battle.append("You can't run in this game you sissy.\n\n");
    }                                   

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton attack;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea battle;
    private javax.swing.JButton charge;
    private javax.swing.JButton heal;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton run;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: See [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You received `AccessControlException` exception which means the operation was not allowed.

You should not call `System.exit()` in the applet. Applets normally not allowed to execute it. As `System.exit()` terminates JVM you may terminate other applets that are currently running in the browser. See [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) for more details.

Redesign the applet to navigate to a document that indicates that the execution of applet is over. You can use `applet.getAppletContext().showDocument()` for that purpose.

Comment: Is there any code that lets me null button actions once it reaches that branch instead? In other words, once it reaches that branch, can I make the applet stop taking responses?

Comment: @user3068063 not sure what you mean.

Comment: In other words, is it possible to make the applet stop taking button actions once it reaches for example, this part of the code.`if(player <= 0)
       {
           battle.append("You have died" + "\n\n");
           System.exit(0);
       }` Even if the user presses any button, nothing will happen.

Comment: @user3068063 yes, you can remove action listener in the same way you added it. But that unnecessarily complicates the UI logic and may only confuse the user. Instead, you may disable buttons so they stop reacting (ie: `attack.setEnabled(false)`), show some indication that the game is over, or navigate to another document that explains that the game is over and how to restart it.

Comment: I removed the system.exit(0) and recompiled it with javac. Then I used jar.exe cvf slime.jar *.class to make a jar but now it's giving me a null pointer exception error. The details don't have anything in it besides a 0.

Comment: @user3068063 Inside `init()` you are referencing `battle` before it is allocated. The allocation occurs in `initComponents` which is executed at the end of `init()`. Move `initComponents` to be the first call in `init()`.

Comment: Would I need to remove the `initComponents` from the `public void run()` then? Or can I move it and still keep it there?

Comment: @user3068063 Correction - `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` should probably be the first thing that is executed in `init()`. As for your question, leave `initComponents` wrapped in `invokeAndWait`. In fact, the rest of the method should also be in `invokeAndWait`. See example of `init` method at [How to Make Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html#thread)

Comment: Thanks! The applet works now! But I noticed that just moving the `initComponents` to the top makes it work fine. I haven't noticed anything besides the fact the text won't scroll down automatically. Are they any other things that I should be aware of if I don't place `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` on top?

Comment: @user3068063 you're welcome, glad it worked out :)  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` sets a `Look and Feel`. It is usually one of the first things at start up. Otherwise, after the L&F is changed during execution, all the components need to be notified about the change, as this affects their appearance. In your case, first setup the L&F, then call `initComponents()`, then the rest of the initialization. See [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for more details.